# Displaying an Online Image Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I have tried getting an online image  to get posted on a UIView however it doesn't load. Can someone help me out

I have used  http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=23024

its not loading, I keep getting errors.

Im trying to build something like http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quotes/id504790688?mt=8

Thank You

Comment: post some code and show errors if you want some answers

Comment: click the link and it will show the code

Comment: Richard do you work as a freelancer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageToShowIfOriginalNotFound.png"]];
```

This is assuming you are using the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) Library

Comment: Alsayed can I have your email address ?